# C++ Remove invisible faces VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I made a VBO cube a while ago, It work's great but it has a lack of performance.
How can I remove invisible faces in a VBO?

I also have a problem with the textures, they are seemed to be messed up :/
If anyone knows something to fix that, it would be great!

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#define OFFSET_BUFFER(bytes) ((GLfloat *)NULL + bytes)

PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC glGenBuffers = NULL;
PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC glBindBuffer = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC glBufferData = NULL;
GLfloat vertex[];
GLuint m_vertexBuffer;
GLuint m_textureBuffer;

void VBOinit()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glBufferData");
#else
glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glGenBuffers");
glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glBindBuffer");
glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)"glBufferData");
#endif
if (!glGenBuffers || !glBindBuffer || !glBufferData)
{
    std::cerr << "VBOs are not supported by your graphics card" << std::endl;
    return;
}

// TEXTURE VBO
GLfloat texture[] =
{
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1,
    0, 1
};

glGenBuffers(1, &m_textureBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_textureBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texture), &texture, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// GEOMETRIC VBO
GLfloat vertex[] =
{
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,      // v0-v0.5f-v2 (front)
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,      // v2-v3-v0
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,      // v0-v3-v4 (right)
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,      // v4-v5-v0
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,      // v0-v5-v6 (top)
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,      // v6-v0.5f-v0
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,      // v0.5f-v6-v7 (left)
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,      // v7-v2-v0.5f
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,      // v7-v4-v3 (bottom)
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,      // v3-v2-v7
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,      // v4-v7-v6 (back)
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f     // v6-v5-v4
};

glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBuffer); //Generate a buffer for the vertices
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer); //Bind the vertex buffer
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex), &vertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); //Send the data to OpenGL
}

void VBOrender(int x, int y, int z)
{
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture::textures[0]);
glTranslatef(x, y, z);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_textureBuffer);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

//glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
}
```

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: How do you define "lack of performance"? A mere cube is not even felt by a modern GPU, it goes more like "huh, did you notice something?".

Comment: It gives me 30+/- fps when rendering 16*16*16 blocks;
Rendering 32*32*32 blocks give me 4 fps

And no, My gpu is not bad, actually I have a good GPU (2gb NVidia GForce gt440)

Comment: Your problem is not the amount of geometry, but the API call overhead. For each cube you perform a call to `glDrawArrays`; it's these calls that suck performance. Try to batch more geometry into a single call of `glDrawArrays`. On modern GPUs the break even when it comes to overhead is, when a single `glDrawArrays` call leads to at least about ~200 triangles being drawn. If you can pack more than 1000 into it, things start to look good. In your case you can use *instancing* to draw all the cubes with just a single `glDraw…` call.

Comment: How can I do that?
I'm new to VBO :)

But how does Removing Faces in VBO work?
Still didn't figure that out.

Comment: You don't remove faces from the VBO. The best you can do is omit them from the list of indices you pass to `glDrawElements` (instead of `glDrawArrays`). A lot of newbies confuse OpenGL with a scene graph, i.e. a system that keeps track of geometry. But that's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL is a drawing API that draws points, lines and triangles to a framebuffer, one point, line or triangle at a time. One it's drawn it already forgot about it. That's why OpenGL does not do things like hidden surface removal. It provides you with depth testing and back face culling, but still processes everything.

Comment: Can you post the code for your draw loop, where you iterate over your 32*32*32 cubes and draw each one? @datenwolf is absolutely right, you won't be able to saturate your GPU with draw calls that are this small. Still, if you don't have a lot of state setup, you should be able to push through a few million draw calls per second. 32*32*32 primitives at 4 fps is 128k draw calls per second. That's much lower than what I would expect. Seeing the draw code will also allow us to give you more targeted advice on how to make your drawing more efficient.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SumCc1wY :)

Comment: Sorry, but where can I find an working VBO tutorial that uses Indices?
Can't find anything on google :/

Comment: Ok. You're repeating a lot of redundant API calls for each cube. You can restructure your code so that all the `glBind*`, `glEnable*`, `glDisable*`, `gl*Pointer` calls are made once before/after the loops. The only thing you really need inside the loops are the `glTranslatef` and `glDrawArrays` calls. That should give you a significant boost. If you're willing to start using your own shaders, there are ways to make the translations more efficient as well.

Comment: Ill do that, but then I still got this Non-Efficient VBO, And I can't find any good tutorials on VBO, That are actually good.

With Indices, DrawElements :/

Comment: Reto Koradiki, I tried what you said, for some reason I cant make it bigger then 16*16*16 or it will give me only 1 fps, white cubes and I cant move.

Comment: If you Google "OpenGL instancing tutorial" you find countless examples.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what went wrong there. I guess I can post the proposed outline in an answer, it wouldn't fit well in a comment. BTW, DrawArrays is at least as efficient as DrawElements, so I don't think that will help you.

Comment: datenwolf, I found some tutorials, but there no for VBO, I rlly don't knowwhat to do know :/

If someone knows a VBO tutorial, please tell me :)

Comment: 'The best you can do is omit them from the list of indices you pass to '

How can I do that?

Comment: Nobody? How can I exclude faces from the buffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding detail on what we started in the comments above, plus a couple more things.

As was previously suggested, add `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. I doubt that it addresses your bottleneck, but it can't hurt.

One other thing you should generally do is store your positions and texture coordinates interleaved in a single buffer, instead of storing them in separate buffers. Again, I think you're limited elsewhere right now, just a general recommendation.

To illustrate what I suggested in the comment about avoiding to set redundant state inside your loop. Right now your structure in pseudo code looks like this:

```
loop over x, y, z
    VBOrender(x, y, z)
end loop
```

Instead, I would structure it like this:

```
VBObind()
loop over x, y, z
    VBOrender(x, y, z)
end loop
VBOunbind()
```

And split up the code in your current `VBOrender` function like this:

```
void VBObind()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture::textures[0]);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_textureBuffer);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));
}

void VBOunbind()
{
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

void VBOrender(int x, int y, int z)
{
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
}
```

I expect that this will give you a significant performance improvement. To get massively better performance, you would need something more dramatic, like packing all the cubes in a single draw call. This looks slightly tricky, though, because from what I can see in [your code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SumCc1wY), the rendering of each cube is conditional.

If you're willing to write your own shaders, you can make the translation an attribute, which would be much faster to update than the fixed function transformation matrix.

Comment: WEll, there is another option, Remove faces.
(Remove some vertex pointers)

But idk how :/

Comment: Edit: Sorry, It work, It was my block array.
But how can i 'Remove faces'

Comment: Anyone know how to 'Remove faces' by removing parts of the vertex array.

Or exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on back-face culling by calling:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CCW); // <- says faces are defined in counter-clockwise order. Change if yours are in clockwise order
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
```

As for your textures, it looks like you've defined texture coordinates for 11 cube faces, but you you have 36 triangles you're drawing. 36 triangles would be 18 quads, so I think you need more texture coordinates.